# React Native: Center ListView inside View container

Tags: ios, listview, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Here is a sample app, where I'm trying to center ListView inside View container:

[image]

Here are the 4 requirements:

- Two-column layout
- The `ListView` element should be centered vertically in both columns
- It should work with both short and long `ListView`
- The long `ListView` should be scrollable once full height was reached

There are still some problems with the app:

- The long `ListView` doesn't allow to scroll
- Other content not visible in column with long `ListView`

[RNPlay (Link)](https://rnplay.org/apps/rKv0gg)

```
'use strict';

import React, { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View, Component, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class SampleApp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
        });
      var ds2 = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
        });
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["SHORT LIST", "SHORT LIST", "SHORT LIST"]),
        dataSource2: ds2.cloneWithRows(["LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST", "LONG LIST"]),
            };
        }

    render() {
      return ( 
        <View style={styles.parentOfParent}>
          <View style={styles.parent}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Other content</Text>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(item) => {return <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>;}}
              style={styles.listview}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listviewContent}
            />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Other content</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.parent}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Other content</Text>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource2}
              renderRow={(item) => {return <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>;}}
              style={styles.listview}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listviewContent}
            />
            <Text style={styles.text}>Other content</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
        }
};

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parentOfParent: {flex:1, flexDirection:'row', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'black'},
    parent: {flex:0.5, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'stretch'},
  listview: {flex:0, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'green'},
  listviewContent: {borderWidth:1, borderColor:'red'},
  text: {fontSize:40, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'yellow'}
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: You can add `flex:0` to the ListView' style, like here: https://rnplay.org/apps/0qnisg

Comment: You are right, I missed the flex parameter.

Comment: But you should test if it still works fine for a long lists as well

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work with this setting, I will update the RNPlay example to feature longer list. *update: it works in RNPlay

Comment: You could try the updated example, there should be this two-column layout. Contents of both columns should be vertically centered and allow scrolling.